# How to represent "end of field" in http response?

Tags: c#, http-headers

I have a C# TCPserver running in Visual Studio.

There is an Android app that needs a simple text answer from it,
but its using a Http request.

When the server sends the answer the android app get this error:

```
 // JAVA.IO.EOFEXEPTION
```

I assume this `End of field` error means I need to add some sort of ending signature or string to my server's response?

Any help on how to do this? Or any other reasons why I am getting this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't know the context but `EOF` could also mean "End of file". Related to this *perhaps* you've to calculate and send the filesize with the header.

Comment: thanks david. you are correct but actually i didnt have a header at all! so  simply  putting a generic copy paste header in front of my responce did the trick.